# how to iterate the key value pair by using hashmap and show in recycleView in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

Data Class

```
data class productAddOnVariations (var name : String? =null, var id :String? =null, var price :String? =null)
```

Adapter

```
class CartAdapter(val product: List<productAddOnVariations>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.customizationViewHolder>(){

    inner class customizationViewHolder(itemView: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val radioButton = itemView.radioButton
        val tvcustomPrice = itemView.tvCustomPrice

    }
    //its show the item count in recycleView
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return product.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: customizationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.radioButton.text = product[position].name
        holder.tvcustomPrice.text =product[position].price
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): customizationViewHolder {
        return  customizationViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.customization_layout,parent,false))
    }
}
```

BootSheet

```
var list1 = document.get("product_add_ons") as List<productAddOnVariations>
val userModel: productAddOnVariations = document.toObject(productAddOnVariations::class.java)!!
var hashMap = HashMap<String,String>()
hashMap.put(list1.toString(),userModel.toString()
for (list1 in userModel.toString()){
    println("$key = $value")
}
cartAdapter = CartAdapter(list1)
rvChooseCustomiztion.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
rvChooseCustomiztion.adapter = cartAdapter
```

We have to read data from firebase and the structure is of array list as show in screenShot so how to print that time of data in recycleView where one side of it is key ="Food Name" and value =30 like this we have to print in recycleview.
[image]

Comment: Besides that `id` property, you have different keys for the other property inside each document. What exactly would you like to display in your RecyclerView?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the reply I want to display like Double cheese  = 30rs like this iterations you can also see in zomato app that if you select any food they show you that you want Extra chees = 20 rs , Extra sugar = 5rs and the data will come from firebase cloud firestore. And for different food different options will be there this things i have to show in recycleView .

Answer (score 0):

It should be better to restructure your Firestore document by adding a third field called `food name` in order to specify "Double cheese", "Extra veggies", etc. there.

It will make it easier to fetch data from your DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FaridShumbar. I already know that to add an extra field everything will we easy but I have a requirement for this way Thankyou.